# How UI test Jetpack Compose using Firebase Test Lab?

Tags: android, firebase, android-jetpack-compose, firebase-test-lab, android-jetpack-compose-testing

For [testing compose layout](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing) we have a default library.

To run [Firebase Test Lab](https://firebase.google.com/docs/test-lab/android/get-started) (FTL) it says you need `Espresso` or `UI Automator` frameworks.

But I'm not sure if this is outdated or not.

Putting my APKs *(that use jetpack compose and the compose testing framework)* to be tested on FTL works on real devices but not virtual devices.

My question is, what is the expected approach?

- Add Espresso to all my UI tests and use Espresso on Jetpack Compose (is this possible?)
- Run FTL with real physical devices only. Virtual to come maybe?
- There is a way to run compose tests on virtual devices and I didn't found.?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there an error or log that you can share from when the test fails on virtual devices?

Comment: Not a log, but it says "Skipped: App doesn't run on the requested device's architecture" but the same architecture on the real device work. Is because the virtual won't recognised

Comment: Many FTL virtual devices run on an x86 host architecture in Google Cloud. If your app is compiled to only ARM code, it won't run on x86 virtual devices. However, FTL recently released beta virtual devices running natively on ARM hardware. Try testing against devices like `MediumPhone.arm`,`SmallPhone.arm`, or `Pixel2.arm` to try these new virtual devices.